# Build a multi-text input model in pytorch

Tags: input, text, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I want to build a model for text comparison. It takes multiple (nearly identically) texts as input, adds padding and vectorizes them on character basis. The output should be, based on the kind of difference between the texts, a number (for example: 2). And no, I can't use a simple distance calculation.

An unvectorized sentence looks like this:

> ɪn deːn ˈgʀɛːbn̩ vɛkst ˈʊntɐ ˈandəʀəm diː ˈzɛltənə ˈkʀeːpsʃeːʀəöööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööö

The ö is padding.
Four of (slightly different) sentences like this are vectorized (one number represents one character) and put together in one tensor look
like this: --> Note, the 69 is the vector for padding

```py
# INPUT
tensor([[ 8,  3,  1, 16,  2, 22,  3,  1,  6, 19, 40, 27, 22, 30,  3, 12,  1,  7,
         27, 20, 67,  4,  1,  6, 25,  3,  4, 23,  1,  6, 14,  3, 16, 18, 40, 18,
         10,  1, 16, 36, 22,  1,  6, 37, 27, 21,  4, 18,  3, 18,  1,  6, 20, 40,
          2, 22, 39, 67, 24, 26,  2, 22, 40, 18, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69],
        [ 8,  3,  1, 16,  2, 22,  3,  1,  6,  4, 40, 14,  8, 15, 30,  3, 12,  1,
          7, 27, 20, 67,  4,  1,  6, 25,  3,  4, 23,  1,  6, 14,  3, 16, 18, 40,
         18, 10,  1, 16, 36, 22,  1,  6, 37, 27, 21,  4, 18,  3, 18,  1,  6, 20,
         40,  2, 22, 39, 67, 24, 26,  2, 22, 40, 18, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69],
        [ 8,  3,  1, 16,  2, 22,  3,  1,  6, 14, 33, 13,  8, 19, 23,  1,  6, 42,
         14, 22, 40, 18,  3,  1, 27,  6, 20, 67, 14, 20,  4, 18,  1,  6, 14,  3,
          7, 14,  8, 15, 37, 25, 17, 18,  3,  1, 16, 36, 22,  1,  6, 37, 27, 21,
          4, 18,  3, 18,  1, 30, 18,  6,  4, 40, 36, 22, 39, 67, 24, 34, 41, 22,
         40, 23, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69],
        [ 8,  3,  1, 16,  2, 22, 19,  3, 12,  1,  6,  4, 40, 14, 22, 19,  3, 12,
          1,  7, 27, 20, 67,  1,  6, 25,  3,  4, 23,  1,  6, 14,  3, 16, 18, 40,
         18,  3,  1, 16, 36, 22,  6, 37, 27, 21,  4,  3, 12,  1,  6,  4, 27, 22,
         39, 67,  4,  1,  6, 26,  2, 22, 40, 23, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69,
         69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69]])

# OUTPUT
tensor([2])
```

For the model I tried using a modified version of the [TextClassificationModel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/text_sentiment_ngrams_tutorial.html)

```py
class TextClassificationModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_class):
        # num_class is the number of different outputs, I set it for testing purposes to 3. Therefore the output can be 0, 1 or 2.
        super(TextClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(70, embed_dim, sparse=True, padding_idx=69)
        # 70 because there are 70 different letters to be substituted, embed_dim is 64 taken over from the tutorial
        self.fc = nn.Linear(embed_dim, num_class)
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        initrange = 0.5
        self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.fc.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.fc.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, text, offsets):
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
        # Size of embedded = torch.Size([4, 250, 3]). | The batch size should be one not four.
        return self.fc(embedded)
```

As you can see my multi-input is seen as a bigger batch size. How can I build a fully-connected multi-input model in Pytorch?

I have to vectorize the sentence on character-for-number level, because the output number may change if just some characters are missing or substituted.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if some code parts are missing.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy to handle this would be to introduce a separator token and concatenate all the sentences (into one) before feeding it into the model.

```
# define a separator token
sep_idx = 70

# create a separator token (sep_idx) for each sentence in input
sep = torch.ones(4, 1) * sep_idx

# append sep_idx to each sentence in input
text = torch.cat((text, sep), 1)

# concatenate all sentences into 1
text = text.reshape(1, -1)
```

Output near end of sentence 1 and start of sentence 2 for your example -

```
text[0, 240:260]
>> tensor([69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 70.,  8.,  3.,  1.,
        16.,  2., 22.,  3.,  1.,  6.])
```

If you use this method, you will also need to update the size of `num_embeddings` to 71 in `nn.Embedding` as you introduced a new token.

This strategy is also used by BERT, read an explanation [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/62856/122848).